# Charts for the complex projective line .

Tags: differential-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

Let $\mathbb{C}P^1$ be the complex projective line quotient of $\mathbb C^2 \setminus \{0\}$ by the equivalence relation :
$$(z_1,z_2) \sim \;(z_1',z_2') \iff \exists \rho \in \mathbb C^*, \quad  (z_1',z_2')=\rho (z_1,z_2) $$
For $i=1,2$, let $U_i=\{[z_1,z_2] \in \mathbb{C}P^1 : z_i \neq0\}$ and $\phi_i : U_i \to \mathbb C$ defined by :
$$\phi_i([z_1,z_2])=\frac{z_2}{z_1} \text{ and } \phi_2([z_1,z_2])= \frac{z_1}{z_2}$$
I want to find $\phi_i ^{-1} $ for $i=1,2.$
I didn't know how to find it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have $[z_1,z_2]=[1,z_2/z_1]$ for $z_1\neq 0$, so I'm not sure what $\phi_1^{-1}$ could be other than $\phi_1^{-1}(w)=[1,w]$.

Comment: I appreciate your help  @Semiclassical :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify that $\phi_1^{-1}(z)=[1,z]$, and similarly for $\phi_2^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you so much ! :) @Berci